# chronology of LaTeX books

Tags: books

Can I get the chronology of books written for LaTeX

For example I have gone through `D._Knuth-The_TeXbook.pdf`

But most of the examples will not compile in the modern Win Cmptr running `MikTex` like `\line \topinsert` etc

What book comes next in the series after the aforementioned TeXbook?

Comment: There's no "book after TheTeXbook"; it's the only TeX manual written by Donald Knuth. There are other books in the same collection (Computers & Typesetting; [see](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513529/134574)), but they are not sequences to The TeXbook. From your description I believe you are trying to compile TeXBook examples in LaTeX: some will work, but some won't. You need to use the `tex` executable (`pdftex` or others might work as well, but The TeXbook is specifically about `tex`).

Comment: By books I meant by any author for example I have started reading `Lamport - LaTex - A Document Preparation System 2e (AW, 1994)`  is this next in the chronology or is there something of value in between

Comment: As I said, there is no "chronology". The TeXbook is about TeX, and LaTeX - A Document Preparation System is about LaTeX. Although LaTeX is build on top of TeX, the usage is very different, so the manuals are equally different. "of value" probably depends on the reader's opinion. I've ever only read half of The TeXbook, so I can't tell about other books, but "TeX by Topic" by Victor Eijkhout is a good reference (but it's about TeX, not LaTeX), and The LaTeX Companion is probably the definitive reference about LaTeX.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24105/134574). See also [here](https://tug.org/books/) and [here](https://www.latex-project.org/help/books/).

Comment: [This list](https://www.ams.org/arc/resources/tex-publications.html) is somewhat dated, but contains a large number of relevant references.